# accessing a static variable in another class

Tags: java, oop, selenium-webdriver

I want to access a class static variable from another class. I have a method which has two String parameters: the name of the class and the name of the static field. Based on these parameters, I would like to return the value of the field on that specific class.

```
Class SignUp {
  public static WebElement userName;
  public static WebElement email;
  public static WebElement phoneNumber;
}

Class Login{
  public static WebElement userName;
  public static WebElement password;
}

Class MyClass{
   String Ele = SupportingClass.getElement("Login","userName");
   //Ele should contain the value of 'userName' on the 'Login' class
}

Class SupportingClass{
  public static String getElement(String name,String pageName){

 //Need to get the pagename.name field here

   }
}
```

Comment: Although this will not compile, that is not a reason to give it a downvote. I think this is a valid question. He just wants to retrieve the value of a static field based on a classname and fieldname.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection for this:

```
public static String getElement(String name,String pageName){
   Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(pageName);
   Field myField = myClass.getDeclaredField(name);
   return myField.get(null);
}
```

pagename should be the fully classified class name, so including the package name.

Code is not tested, so possibly some syntactic errors here...

Comment: Because he has a getElement method in which he passes the name of a class and the name of a field. And he wants to retrieve the field value based on these names.

Comment: I must admit I was not attentive while reading original question. So I'm sorry for downvoting your answer. If you edit it, I will upvote it (cannot do it now)

Comment: I'd hesitate to promote the usage of reflection to cure an ill-fated class design! OP might be better of by using a HashMap or the like to store the navigation data...

Comment: @GyroGearless The question was how to retrieve a value based on the name of a field. The only way to do that is using reflection. Whether you like to use it or not... But of course that doesn't prevent you from giving a different, more elaborate answer...